# android studio will not recognize my device and my emulator will not load

Tags: htc-one, android-sdk

Android studio recognized my device before, but now it doesn't. It is an HTC One. I have the driver downloaded, so it's not that.
I am trying to use an emulator but it won't load either. I have to use ARM because my computer can't use HAXM.  It starts to load but never finishes.
I need help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your device is connected to the computer and run `adb device` in command prompt (you may have to browse to `<Android-SDK>/platform-tools`. See if adb displays your device. If it doesn't, go to Settings > Developer Settings  and select Revoke USB debugging authorizations. Disconnect and reconnect your phone and authorize it to be debugged through the computer.